# Convert a react component into pre-rendered static html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple react component. Assume it as the default animated logo when the app is created

I now need to inject this component on top of a webpage using my chrome extension. I know how to inject a html template code along with its css and js through a chrome extension

I tried `npm run build` to generate static files so as to inject all those through my extension.
But that doesn't work. When the built `index.html` is injected onto someother page, it doesn't render there. Its just injected as root and **nothing inside is rendered**

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Is there a solution on how I can get the a pre rendered static html of my react component so that I can use it to inject through my chrome extension

```
<div id="root">
   <img src="a.png">
   <h1>Sample text</h1>
   .....
</div>
```

Above is how I want the rendered html of that component needs to be

Answer (score 0):

> When the built index.html is injected onto someother page, it doesn't
> render there. Its just injected as root and nothing inside is rendered

Did you inject just the index.html file? When you do `npm run build` there are other files as well that are generated and are needed for the index.html to work. Mainly the chunk.js file and css files.

They need to be in the same directory as the rendered index html file(You might have to replace the relative paths with absolute paths to make it work, if you are not able to put the files in the same directory).

Further reference: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build

Comment: I injected the index.html removing all references to CSS and JS files.
But I added those CSS and JS files in the content script section. I added all the CSS and JS files which were there in the build directory.
Now the HTML page, CSS and JS run in the same website's context to which they got injected into. 
They are linked